# How can i set character limit in quill editor

Tags: angular, quill

> I am using Quill Editor in angular 2, and want to limit the user to
>   enter maximum 1000 char.

Answer (score 10):

There is as far as I know no built in configuration for that. You can however delete input that exceeds a certain length.

Example code from [this](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/688#issuecomment-259500970) github issue

```
const limit = 1000;

quill.on('text-change', function (delta, old, source) {
  if (quill.getLength() > limit) {
    quill.deleteText(limit, quill.getLength());
  }
});
```

It is not clear if you are using pure quill or something like [ngx-quill](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill) so I cannot provide a full example. Provide more details if you want additional help with integrating it in angular.

Remember to to `quill.off(...)` for your text-change handler on `ngOnDestroy` to prevent leaks.

## Edit

*Solution added using the [ngx-quill](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill) module.*

#### Editor component

*editor.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

const MAX_LENGTH = 10;

@Component({
  selector: 'editor',
  templateUrl: './editor.component.html',
})
export class EditorComponent {
  /*
   * Delete added characters that exceeds max length
   */
  textChanged($event) {
    if ($event.editor.getLength() > MAX_LENGTH) {
      $event.editor.deleteText(MAX_LENGTH, $event.editor.getLength());
    }
  }
}
```

#### Editor template

*editor.template.html*

```
<quill-editor (onContentChanged)="textChanged($event)"></quill-editor>
```

Comment: I am using  angular 2 module for quill

Comment: @NirajBharti See my latest edit for an implementation with ngx-quill

Comment: Be careful with this solution as only works if user is adding text at the end. What happens if user tries to add text in the middle?

Comment: And even more, try to see how it works if you wrap entire content with 5-10 tags, try to make whole content bold and then italic when it reached maximum already. Real length will be more than your maximum value. So, this somehow works, but doesn't Instead of cutting content, block your form and show counter as red (if you have one) or additional error message below.

Comment: but this is not taking in consideration the html, i limited it to MAX_LEGNT=20 characters but if you put one character every new line you end up with a length of more than 80 because each line is wrapped by a `<p></p>` by default

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example using [ngx-quill](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill).

One approach of doing this would be setting the maxLength to the desired number and show an error to the user. In addition, the action can be blocked until the user fixes it.

#### See Image:

[image]

In here, I have added minLength and maxLength properties. It will display a message below the editor and disable the action button. Only when the validation is met, the button will be made active.

#### See Code Here:

```
    <quill-editor [style]="{height: '200px'}" name="notes" 
      [(ngModel)]="note" [minLength]="10" [maxLength]="400" 
       #noteInput="ngModel"></quill-editor>

    <span class="hints" *ngIf="!noteInput.valid">
      Min 10 characters and note more than 400</span>

   <button fxFlexAlign="end" mat-raised-button color="primary" 
     class="btn--rounded" (click)="addNote()" 
     [disabled]="!ticketNoteInput.valid">Add</button>
```

Comment: Could you please share the full code?

Answer (score 3):

There are inbuilt configurations to support minimum length and maximum length validations. However  it doesn't  add 'errors.minlength' class. It will only add 'ng-invalid' class.

```
<quill-editor [(ngModel)]="topic.description" [bounds]="'self'"  [minLength]="'5'"   #topicDesc="ngModel">
```

```
<span *ngIf="!topicDesc.valid" class="requiredField">
                Topic Description is required
</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of using `quill.deleteText()` method for deleting all the extra text,

you can use `quill.formatText()` method to make all the unwanted text into color red.

like this >>>

```
quill.on('text-change', (e) => {
  quill.formatText(100, 5000, {                   
    'color': 'rgb(220, 20, 60)'
  });
});
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it in Angular 7 by adding below code.

```
@ViewChild('editor') editor: Editor;
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.editor.writeValue(data);
    this.editor.quill.setSelection(null, data.length, null);
  }, 100);
```

Comment: Where I add this Code?

Comment: In your .ts file.

Comment: can you please add this code to stackblitz? https://stackblitz.com/edit/text-editor-quill-qwunti?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: please share any sample code for maxlength validations

Answer (score 1):

Also for ngx-quill, a variant of the jgranstrom's proposal focused on controlling HTML length. A Typescript code, kind of a simple workaround but still usable.

```
onContentChanged(context: ChangeContext) {

 console.log('Content changed: ', context);
 if (context == null || context.html == null) { return; }

 // A HTML - focused version of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803413/how-can-i-set-character-limit-in-quill-editor
 // It does cause an error log in the console: 'The given range isn't in document.'
 // Still it's a simple and effective solution.
 if (context.html.length > RESOURCE_TEXT_MAX_LENGTH) {
   let oldDelta = context['oldDelta'];
   if (oldDelta == null) { return; }
   context.editor.setContents(oldDelta.ops);
 }
}
```